# What's the most sound interpretation of quran 39:4?

Tags: tafseer, quran-translation, uloom-al-quran

I have gone through this verse and have read numerous exegesis but still I'm not able to comprehend this verse fully. What's the context of this verse and how does the verse saying "If Allah had willed to take a son, He may had chosen among his creation whoever He willed" negate the fact that Allah can't have a son?

Answer (score 0):

This verse states that Allah has never chosen anyone as His son. And if he wanted, he could do so, and he would declare it through his prophets and in the various authentic versions of sacred books, specifically the Quran. Allah does not need humans to choose someone as His son.

This verse primarily discusses the belief held by Christians that Jesus is the Son of God. In authentic and undistorted Christianity, there is no son for Allah.

[Refrence](https://quran.inoor.ir/fa/ayah/39/4/commentary?language=1)